# Testing Rails 3.1 engine routes with RSpec 2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rails-engines

I'm trying to test a Rails 3.1 engine with RSpec 2.  After a lot of trial and error (and documentation and Stack Overflow searching) the app is working and I've gotten most of the specs to pass.  The problem is that my route specs are still failing.

For an engine "foo" with an isolated namespace and a controller Foo::BarsController, I have this:

```
require "spec_helper"

describe Foo::BarsController do
  describe "routing" do
    it "routes to #index" do
      get("/foo/bars").should route_to("bars#index")
    end

    it "routes to #new" do
      get("/foo/bars/new").should route_to("bars#new")
    end
  end
end
```

This results in:

```
1) Foo::BarsController routing routes to #index
   Failure/Error: get("/foo/bars").should route_to("bars#index")
   ActionController::RoutingError:
     No route matches "/foo/bars"
   # ./spec/routing/foo/bars_routing_spec.rb:6:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

2) Foo::BarsController routing routes to #new
   Failure/Error: get("/foo/bars/new").should route_to("bars#new")
   ActionController::RoutingError:
     No route matches "/foo/bars/new"
   # ./spec/routing/foo/bars_routing_spec.rb:10:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

My spec dummy application seems to be set up correctly:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  mount Foo::Engine => "/foo"
end
```

If it helps to answer this question, my view specs are also not working.  Here is a typical error:

```
9) foo/bars/index.html.erb renders a list of bars
   Failure/Error: render
   ActionView::Template::Error:
     undefined local variable or method `new_bar_path' for #<#<Class:0x00000100c14958>:0x0000010464ceb8>
   # ./app/views/foo/bars/index.html.erb:3:in `___sers_matt__ites_foo_app_views_foo_bars_index_html_erb___1743631507081160226_2184232780'
   # ./spec/views/foo/bars/index.html.erb_spec.rb:12:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I got this working!  And wrote a blog post about it.

http://www.matthewratzloff.com/blog/2011/09/21/testing-routes-with-rails-3-1-engines/

It requires a new method to import engine routes into the application route set for tests.

Edit: Caught a bug with named route handling and fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your `get` method to use the specific route

```
get("/foo/bars", :use_route => :foo)
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. `ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)`

Comment: I think the confusion comes from the fact that `get` in this context is RSpec's `get` method, whereas above it's the Rails method.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually not so hard to get this to work. It's a bit hacky since you are adding code to the engine's routes.rb file that changes depending on which env it's running in. If you are using the spec/dummy [site approach](http://reinteractive.net/posts/2-start-your-engines) for testing the engine then use the following code snippet in /config/routes.rb file:

```
# <your_engine>/config/routes.rb

if Rails.env.test? && Rails.application.class.name.to_s == 'Dummy::Application'
 application = Rails.application
else
 application = YourEngine::Engine
end

application.routes.draw do
 ...
end
```

What this is basically doing is switching out your engine for the dummy app and writing the routes to it when in test mode.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the official rspec documentation solution:

https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/routing-specs/engine-routes